# How do we check how often someone is running queries in Azure SQL?

Tags: azure-sql-database

We have to collect some information. How do we check how often someone is running queries in Azure SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Use extended events to trace all the queries running on your Azure SQL database. Also, you can save the output in a file and can query from clients tools like SSMS.

You can also use auditing provided by Azure SQL. Please check below link for details:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auditing-overview#:~:text=Go%20to%20the%20Azure%20portal,modify%20the%20server%20auditing%20settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auditing-overview#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20Azure%20portal,modify%20the%20server%20auditing%20settings).